# Cannot use NTFS drive as non-root user

Tags: linux, files, fedora

I have an NTFS partition which I am trying to mount as Read Write in Fedora 22. Using Nautilus as root allows me to create folders, files etc. However when I use my non root account, I get an "Error while copying to "Data" The destination is read-only" error.

I have changed the permission and ownership of the whole mount point to my non-root account and even specified the user and group ids in the mount options.

My Mount Options: nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,remove_hiberfile,rw,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000

Answer (score 0):

I recall there may a problem when using nautilus to do the mount of ntfs partitions. Instead use the `sudo mount` command to mount the filesystem using an `/etc/fstab` entry with your options, and you should then be able to use it as a user.